# Is it possible to create a linked list that can hold pointers instead of integers or string?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, linked-list

I'm new to programming but I have a question about linked lists. I am creating a double linked list and I want my nodes to store pointers not just strings or ints. Would code like this work?

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node {
        string name;
        int age;
        int location;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
        Node(T info){ name = info->getName(); age = info->getAge; location = info->getLocation; next = NULL; previous = NULL; }


    };
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
```

This is assuming that (T info) is a pointer to a class object that has been created from:

```
#include "Person.h"


Person::Person(string name, int age, int location)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
    this->location = location;
}


Person::~Person()
{
}

string Person::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Person::getAge()
{
    return age;
}

int Person::getLocation()
{
    return location;
}
```

I want to be able to create a Person from my person class and then store that person (name, age, and location) in my linked list:

```
Person* newPerson = new Person(name, age, location);
LL.insert(newPerson);
```

LL is a linked list I created inside my main.cpp and insert is a function of my linked list.

Maybe this isn't the best way to do this but can I do this?

Comment: yes. its your list.. are u getting any error? or is this more of a design question?

Comment: I recommend to learn using the STL. Is there a reason why you want to reinvent a wheel? Have a look at `list` for example

Comment: As mentioned, look at [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) to see the interface for a linked-list container that works with any type.  However, you should be aware that you should prefer [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) over other containers.  With modern systems, the memory latency hierarchy makes vectors more efficient than lists.

Answer (score 3):

A linked list is a data structure that defines a certain relationship between multiple items of data.

That data is usually strings, or ints, as you noted. But it can be anything.

You can think of a link list as a bookshelf. You typically put books on a bookshelf. But you can also put your shoes up there, and the shoes will sit on the bookshelf the same way as books do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can hold pointers to other objects. In your case a person object.

You need a new class or struct, then create a pointer to that.

```
class LinkedList
{
    private:
    struct Node {
        Person *person;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
};
```

Alternately you can use a linked list of void pointers

```
class LinkedList
{
    private:
    struct Node {
        void *data;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
};
```

Using a templated type you can ensure that the contents are all of the same type.

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
       private:
       struct Node {
          T    *data; 
          Node *next;
       };
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
};
```

I don't have access to a a C++ compiler at this moment so the syntax may need correction.

By the way use of a tail member seems to imply you're trying for a doubly linked list. If you don't need to go backwards in the list this isn't necessary.

Comment: you can always copy/paste your code into http://gcc.godbolt.org/ (where it will be compiled as c++, not c.  AFAIK, godbolt doesn't have a proper C option.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the tip. Wasn't aware of it.